# How to tell phpMyAdmin to use next auto increment value during insert?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

If you try to insert a new record through phpMyAdmin interface to a table that has auto increment primary index field, it requires you to manually enter value for this field. If you don't enter anything it throws an error. How to make it just use auto increment value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into tbl (id,...) values (0,...);  <-- use zero
```

> If a user specifies NULL or 0 for the AUTO_INCREMENT column in an INSERT, InnoDB treats the row as if the value had not been specified and generates a new value for it.

---

> No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly assign NULL or 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass NULL value to the primary field. 
Below is the sample query..

```
insert into tbl (id,...) values (NULL,...);
```

Hope this will help.

Thanks!

Hussain.

Comment: Primary key can't be null, plus it doesn't allow me to enter it (if I type `null` it tries to insert it as a string)

Comment: exactly, null is not null in phpmyadmin ... can consider to ditch or use it occasionally

Comment: Here is sample query, test is primary key.. INSERT INTO `test` (
`test` ,
`test2`
)
VALUES (
NULL , '3'
);

Comment: As a query it might work, but I am trying to use phpmyadmin interface

Comment: Then keep that column empty while you are inserting through the phpMyAdmin form interface..

Comment: Hm, empty works too, don't know why it wasn't working before. Here is +1 for you then.

Answer (score 0):

I was using PreparedStatement and I was having a hard time using the autoincrement.
In my case you just have to do this

```
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 0);
```

1 is the index of the column , 0 increments the value to the next one in the sequence.